# Why does this command work for logging script output?

Tags: ubuntu, logs, tee

This command does not store the output of my script in the log file:

```
. myscript.sh | tee -a log_file.log
```

However this next command *does* store the output in the log file.

```
. myscript.sh 2>&1 | tee -a dash_log.log
```

Why does the second one work and not the first? AFAIK the only difference is that I have told bash to redirect stderr to stdout, and it should not make any difference to what happens with stdout. Yet that first command would not even store the 'error-less' version of stdout in the log file.

And in case it matters: I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 hosted on AWS

EDIT: This was caused by erroneous assumptions of how wget outputs messages. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066518/why-does-wget-output-to-stderr-rather-than-stdout and http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Logging-and-Input-File-Options.html

Comment: can i see the script ?

Comment: I'd rather not include the script actually. The script starts with `source ~/.bashrc`, then loops through some urls calling `wget "theurl.com" --output-document="local/dir/theurl.com"` for each one. All the script output comes from wget.

Comment: and there are no errors from wget, with each entry in the log being of the form something like`timestamp - url; transfer messages; "Saving to: ..."; 0K .......... 31.9M=0s`

Comment: do you have anywhere this: 1>&2? Either in the script itself or in .bashrc which you are sourcing.

Comment: @DanilaLadner no that doesn't appear in the script

Comment: Looks like the question is getting downvoted - I'd appreciate an explanation as too why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems likely that your script is writing most or all of it's output to stderr.
This is easy to test

```
myscript.sh > std.out
myscript.sh 2> err.out
```

then look at the contents of each file and be educated.

---

> I doubt it - the only output from the script comes from calls to wget

Instead of doubting, again this is easy to test

```
$ wget http://serverfault.com >std.out
--2013-09-09 07:06:25--  http://serverfault.com/
Resolving serverfault.com... 198.252.206.16
Connecting to serverfault.com|198.252.206.16|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 51867 (51K) [text/html]
Saving to: “index.html.6”

100%[=================================================>] 51,867   231K/s  in 0.2s

2013-09-09 07:06:26 (231 KB/s) - “index.html.6” saved [51867/51867]
```

See, output still gets written to the terminal then try

```
 $ wget http://serverfault.com 2>err.out
 $
```

Q.E.D.

The wget command writes it's output to stderr not stdout.

Comment: I stand corrected. While it's not clear at all to me why wget would publish "standard" output messages that are *not* about errors to stderr, that is indeed what it is doing. Not a safe assumption to make at all.

Comment: I've always figured it writes to STDERR so that if you `wget -o -` the messages from wget wont get mixed with the payload.

Comment: @PetterH good point - I did discover that on reading the man page, but it still doesn't feel right. I've continued discussion at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2173318

Answer (score 1):

Would probably need to see the code but it is probably due to your code writing out to stderr.

Comment: I doubt it - the only output from the script comes from calls to `wget`, which completes normally multiple times during the script.